# Implementing INotifyCollectionChanged interface

Tags: wpf, data-binding, observablecollection, inotifycollectionchanged

I need to implement a collection with special capabilities. In addition, I want to bind this collection to a ListView, Therefore I ended up with the next code (I omitted some methods to make it shorter here in the forum):

```
public class myCollection<T> : INotifyCollectionChanged
{
    private Collection<T> collection = new Collection<T>();
    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        collection.Insert(collection.Count, item);
        OnCollectionChange(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, item));
    }

    protected virtual void OnCollectionChange(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (CollectionChanged != null)
            CollectionChanged(this, e);
    }
}
```

I wanted to test it with a simple data class:

```
public class Person
{
    public string GivenName { get; set; }
    public string SurName { get; set; }
}
```

So I created an instance of myCollection class as follows:

```
myCollection<Person> _PersonCollection = new myCollection<Person>();
public myCollection<Person> PersonCollection
{ get { return _PersonCollection; } }
```

The problem is that the ListView does not update when the collection updates although I implemented the INotifyCollectionChanged interface.

I know that my binding is fine (in XAML) because when I use the ObservableCollecion class instead of myCollecion class like this:

```
 ObservableCollection<Person> _PersonCollection = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
    public ObservableCollection<Person> PersonCollection
    { get { return _PersonCollection; } }
```

the ListView updates

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

In order for your collection to be consumed, you should implement IEnumerable and IEnumerator too.  Although, you're probably better off subclassing `ObservableCollection<T>`

Comment: Better yet, implement `IList<T>`

Comment: Yes, or inherit from Collection<T>.  ObservableCollection<T> also implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: The thing is that ObservableCollection<T> has many public methods that I don't want the users of my class to have access to, and if I subclass ObservableCollection<T> I have no control of that.

Comment: Such as?  What about inheriting from ReadOnlyObservableCollection? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668620.aspx

Comment: For example, I want the collection to behave in a simillar way to a queue (inserting items only to the end of the collection and deleting items only from the head of the collection). Therefore I want to forbid the use of: public void Insert(int index, T item);